# Should I write a follow up email? (UK Academic position)

Tags: job, united-kingdom, interview, lecturer

I had an interview for a lecturer position on a Friday. The panel mentioned they would give an answer the following week. The week has passed and Im wondering if I should contact them with a follow up email asking kindly for an update. I know for sure that they have interviewed all the candidates they are interested in (we all got interviewed on the same day).
Should I send a follow up email?

Answer (score 2):

I interviewed twice in the UK when I was a postdoc on the academic market.

The first time, I was notified after two weeks that I was not getting an offer.

The second time, I interviewed Friday, flew back to the US on Sunday, and was contacted with an offer on Tuesday. I took a week to weigh competing offers and politely declined on Friday of that week. They proceeded to counter-offer as much as they could (pay scale is set, but I was bumped one) on the Monday. I anticipate after that they went after choice #2.

I could be wrong, but my guess is you are not the first choice, and until they can get a commitment from the first (or subsequent) choices, you will not be notified.

Best of luck